# Why does argparse give me a list-in-a-list?

Tags: python, argparse

I just noticed a behavior in argparse that puzzled me (guess I'd never used it for a dumb list of files before):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('multi', action='append', nargs='+')
print(parser.parse_args())
```

This gives me the output:

```
~$ ./testargs.py foo bar baz
Namespace(multi=[['foo', 'bar', 'baz']])
~$
```

I expected `multi` to be `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`, not a list within a list. As-is, I'll have to grab `args.multi[0]` before processing, which isn't a big deal, but feels like an ugly wart, and I'd like to understand why it's there.

Am I doing something silly in `add_argument`, or is this just an unavoidable quirk?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are calling

```
parser.add_argument('multi', action='append', nargs='+')
```

And it is taking all the arguments and appending as a single item in the multi list.

If you want it as individual items, just don't use append

```
parser.add_argument('multi', nargs='+')
```

From the docs

'append' - This stores a list, and appends each argument value to the list. This is useful to allow an option to be specified multiple times. Example usage:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo 1 --foo 2'.split())
Namespace(foo=['1', '2'])
```

Comment: Huh, you're right. I got the wrong impression from the docs. Maybe I should see if I can send a patch with better wording on a few things. :) Thanks!

Comment: However, note that without `action='append'`, previous values will be discarded if the option is specified multiple times. e.g. `argv=['--foo', 'a', 'b', '--foo', 'c']` will give `Namespace(foo=['c'])` for `add_argument('--foo', nargs='+')`.

Comment: Is there a way to have both options? Multiple --foo or single --foo argument resulting in a single list of strings?